# Show that $\arctan(\tan x)= x-k\pi$

Tags: calculus

Show that there is $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ for every $x \in ( -\pi/2+k\pi ;\pi/2+k\pi$) such that, $$\arctan(\tan x)=x-k\pi$$

**My Try.**

> $$\tan (\arctan(x) ) = \tan (x -k\pi)$$
>   I am not sure if we are working on the same interval to show that.

Any hint ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered the ranges of $\tan$ and $\arctan$?

Comment: The one who edited the question deleted what i tried

Comment: Weird. He/she shouldn't have, generally mathSE encourages someone to try before being given hints.

Comment: I wanna multipy the both sides of the equation in tan so we will have $tan( arctan(x))=tan(x-k\pi)$

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: The hardest part of this is not the actual math but the understanding what is being asked.  tan is a periodic function.  It has an inverse but the inverse returns to a restricted range.  for points originally outside the range arctan(tan(x)) will return a point within the restricted range.  So the question is to show that $\overline{x} = arctan(tan(x))$ will be equivalent to x but maybe different value from x being offset by a multiple of $\pi$-- which is the period of the function tan.  In other words $\overline{x}=\arctan(\tan(x)) = x \pm k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: ..... assuming $x \ne \pi/2 \pm m\pi$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $-\pi/2 + k\pi < x < \pi/2 + k\pi$

Let $y = x - k\pi$.  Then $-\pi/2 < y < \pi/2$.

$\arctan(\tan(y)) = y$ by... well, definition, right?

Now $\tan(x) = \tan(x - k\pi) = \tan(y)$ because $\tan$ has a period of $\pi$.

So $\arctan(\tan(x)) = \arctan(\tan(y)) = y = x - k\pi$.

=====

I don't think the problem was to actually do any hard math, so much as to get the student used to the idea that although arctan is the inverse of tan, for periodic functions inverses return a limited range.  So it is *NOT* the case that $f^{-1}f(x) = x$ but it **is** the case that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x + $ some offset by a multiple of the period of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

$tan^{-1}(tan(x)) = x - k\pi$

$tan(x) = tan(x -k\pi)$

$tan(x) = \frac{tan(x) + tan(-k\pi)}{1-tan(x)tan(-k\pi)}$

---

As $k$ is an integer, what does that tell us about $tan(-k\pi)$?

Hint: $tan(-2\pi) = tan(-\pi)= tan(\pi) = tan(2\pi) = tan(3\pi) = ... $